# Bootstrap table responsiveness

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, html-table

I am at a beginner phase in ReactJS. I am currently using Bootstrap 3. I have created a table with 6 columns like below:

```
<div className="col-md-12">
  <div className="table-responsive">
    <StudentBody
      data={studentList}
      searchText={this.state.text}
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

By using **CSS** on hover over a **TR** I have displayed the **DELETE** link at its last column. Everything is working in an expected manner. But the problem arose when I hovered over any **TR** and the **DELETE** displays, all columns shift towards right and when not hovered it shifts towards its initial position. How do I stop this shifting behavior of columns?
I don't know where it went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what logic you are using to hide the delete button. You can do it by applying a CSS class with visibility:hidden. Do not use display:none

visibility:hidden hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout.

display:none removes the element from the document. It does not take up any space.

Comment: Thanks it worked!!! Yes you are correct, I was using CSS `display:none;` and `display: inline-block;` to hide and show the link as I couldn't achieve the result with mouse events. The state for **mouseenter state** just didn't change when mouse leaves from one **TR** to another, it changed only when mouse pointed outside the **Table** component.

Comment: Good luck with your project. Please also use some click event or similar logic to account for usage on mobile phones.

Answer (score 0):

You should add 
`position:absolute` 
to the delete link and

make the TR `position:relative`

This will ensure that the columns doesn't shift in position when hovered

More about CSS position [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)